# Display menu items as column based on condition

Tags: html, css, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I have created a menu, i need help in display of menu subitems

I have created a plunker. Please go through this to get idea of what i want (open plunker in full screen)
https://plnkr.co/edit/IMEJFPfl5kavKvnUYaRy?p=preview

In the above plunker i have two dropdown menu ('List' and 'Dropdown').
 'List' is hardcoded value and i want to display the submenu as it is here in 'Dropdown' when i get dynamic data.
'Dropdown' is getting submenu items as below,

```
 $scope.items = [
        {
            "Name": "Item1",
            "Url": ""
        },
    {
            "Name": "List1",
            "Url": "www.google.com"
        },
    {
            "Name": "List2",
            "Url": "www.google.com"
        },
    {
            "Name": "Item2",
            "Url": ""
        },
    {
            "Name": "List1",
            "Url": "www.w3schools.com"
        },
    {
            "Name": "List2",
            "Url": "www.w3schools.com"
        }
      ]
```

here if "Url" =="", then it should display in bold and until i get one more "Url" =="" all other items should diplay under it. Ideally when "Url" =="" then it should move to next column. So my html should look as below with the above data

```
<div class="col-sm-2" >
              <li><strong>Item1</strong></li>
              <li>list1</li>
              <li>list2</li>
</div>

<div class="col-sm-2" >
              <li><strong>Item2</strong></li>
              <li>list1</li>
              <li>list2</li>
</div>
```

in plunker i have done item whose "Url" =="" to display in bold, but everything is displaying in single column. As soon as i find "Url" =="" in ng-repeat i want to move to other column. How can i do this? 
  I tried writting condition like below,

```
 <ul data-ng-class="{'col-sm-3 list-unstyled': item.Url==''}" data-ng-repeat="item in items">
```

but only items with "Url" =="" is moving to next column, successive items are not. Please help to me to make 'Dropdown' display like 'List' as shown in plunker.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know why people are giving minus points to this question. If answer is so easy then please let me know. I am struggling to do it from so many days. If you have not understood the question then let me know, I will make it clear. I tried my best to convey the question.